# Problem requiring native c++ addon from electron

Tags: node.js, electron, node.js-addon

Error when I require a Native Addon C++ from electron that works fin from Node.js

Recently I developed my first native C++ Addon for node that works fine with my node project (node version 10.15.0)
The Addon has been built using XCode, which project has been generating using CMake.

I´m having the following error when I use the same native C++  addon from my Electron app.

*dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: __ZN2v816**FunctionTemplate**3**New**EPNS_7IsolateEPFvRKNS_20FunctionCallbackInfoINS_5ValueEEEENS_5LocalIS4_EENSA_INS_9SignatureEEEiNS_19ConstructorBehaviorENS_14SideEffectTypeE
  Referenced from: /Users/vicentvidal/Documents/Desarrollo/DASNet2/dasaudio/build/DASNetAddon.node
  Expected in: flat namespace
dyld: Symbol not found: __ZN2v816FunctionTemplate3NewEPNS_7IsolateEPFvRKNS_20FunctionCallbackInfoINS_5ValueEEEENS_5LocalIS4_EENSA_INS_9SignatureEEEiNS_19ConstructorBehaviorENS_14SideEffectTypeE
  Referenced from: /Users/vicentvidal/Documents/Desarrollo/DASNet2/dasaudio/build/DASNetAddon.node
  Expected in: flat namespace*

As I can see the problem appears just when I call from my Electron App

*const addon = require('bindings')('DASNetAddon');*

which call the following C++ code

```
static NAN_MODULE_INIT(Init) {
    v8::Local<v8::FunctionTemplate> tpl = Nan::New<v8::FunctionTemplate>(New);
    tpl->SetClassName(Nan::New("StreamingWorker").ToLocalChecked());
    tpl->InstanceTemplate()->SetInternalFieldCount(2);

    SetPrototypeMethod(tpl, "sendToAddon", sendToAddon);

    constructor().Reset(Nan::GetFunction(tpl).ToLocalChecked());
    Nan::Set(target, Nan::New("StreamingWorker").ToLocalChecked(),
        Nan::GetFunction(tpl).ToLocalChecked());
}
```

My Electron version is 3.0.10
My Nan version 2.12.1
My bindings version 1.3.1

Does anybody has any suggestion?

Comment: If it's your first addon I suggest you consider using N-API or the C++ node-addon-api built on top of N-API. I am in the process of converting old Nan code to node-addon-api and it's a dramatic improvement.

Comment: btw, I answered below only because when I was first making addons work it was a lonely effort. it's hard to find help and examples that mirror real-world scenarios. another suggestion even though it's probably a bit like drinking the ocean - Microsoft's vscode is an electron app. I'll bet there are some addons in the code base - those might give a clue if you can't find the answer another way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive that this is the problem but it is possible that, because the function template is missing your C++ class name, the namespace is coming from somewhere else. Here's one of my Nan Init() functions. The line following the `// Prepare constructor template` qualifies the `New` argument with a class namespace.

```
void Metadata::Init(v8::Local<v8::Object> exports) {
  Nan::HandleScope scope;

  // Prepare constructor template
  v8::Local<v8::FunctionTemplate> ctor = Nan::New<v8::FunctionTemplate>(Metadata::New);
  constructor.Reset(ctor);
  ctor->InstanceTemplate()->SetInternalFieldCount(2);
  ctor->SetClassName(Nan::New("Metadata").ToLocalChecked());


  // Prototype
  Nan::SetPrototypeMethod(ctor, "copy", Metadata::copy);

  Nan::Set(exports, Nan::New("Metadata").ToLocalChecked(), ctor->GetFunction());
}
```

I haven't tried running/loading in an Electron environment, nor on a Mac, so I can only say this works fine on Linux. But because your error message refers to "FunctionTemplate3New" it's a guess.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I´ll look into your solution and I´ll report you the results.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.

After trying your solution the following error arises:

“Call to non-static member function without an object argument”

At NODE_MODULE(DASNetAddon, CoreWorkerWrapper::Init)

Do you have any idea? Please, feel free to ignore this question if it bothers you.

Comment: Don't know; I'd check the Init function signature and the New function signature. But without the code it's really hard for me to guess. It doesn't bother me at all. I just wish I could help.